# How can I add and fetch data from database in magento

Tags: magento

I had to download  free plug-in and install in my local.

I want to add a new field in register page, but In plugin there's also some new fields in register page and I follow the steps, they do to add new field, I can view the fields what i add in register page.but I can't update the table. 
So I went to database and alter it. and store some value. Now I can't fetch the value.
If I did anything wrong, please guide me further.

Can insert data without install it again option.

Comment: What is not working ? the fields added by you or added by extension ? Which extension you are using ?

Comment: Im using CedCsmarketplace extension. Extension works fine. im getting struggle to data in newfield which is created by me